# IP header , raw socket in C on OpenBSD

Tags: c, sockets, header, ip, openbsd

why does this not work on openBSD.
i got this error:

error:request for member ‘ip_hl’ in something not  structure or union

error: request for member ‘ip_v’ in something not structure or union

and so on...

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in_systm.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int mahoosocket, mahoo;
char data[4096];
struct sockaddr_in sin;
struct tcphdr tcp;
struct ip *ip =(struct ip *)data;

if (argc != 2)
```

(....)

```
 memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
 sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
 sin.sin_port = 0;
```

.(...)

```
ip.ip_hl=5;
ip.ip_v =4;
ip.ip_tos =0;
ip.ip_id = htonl (54321);
ip.ip_off=0;
ip.ip_ttl=255;
ip.ip_p=6;
ip.ip_sum=0;
ip.ip_src.s_addr= inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");    


(.....)
```

Comment: Nothing like asking a question, getting an answer, and then deleting your account.

Answer (score 3):

`ip` is a pointer:

```
struct ip *ip =(struct ip *)data;
```

When accessing members with a pointer-to-struct, you use `->` not `.`

```
ip->ip_hl = 5;
ip->ip_v = 4;
ip->ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");
```

This is basic C syntax you should familiarize yourself with.

Comment: thanks, but if i wrote the code with a tcp header tcp.th_sport=htons(4567) etc ; i can compile the code, so i thought i t would be also correct for the ip header ??

Comment: @mahoo Do you understand that `*` means pointer?  If not, you should honestly work through some tutorials before trying TCP raw socket programming!

Comment: @mahoo Also - like you've *somewhat* done, you often allocate a buffer, and then set up some pointers for the IP header, TCP header, etc. to point to the *correct* locations in the buffer. Then use those pointers to fill in the fields in the buffer.  That is **not** what you're doing with a `struct tcphdr` on the stack.

Comment: ahh sorry, now i understand. i am very new on C. thanks i appreciate your patience

Comment: @mahoo Just trying to make sure you're not jumping in the deep end. Welcome to Stack Overflow, and good luck.

Comment: i hope not :) i should sleep . long time not slept. i appreciate ypur fast help